# How to pass Stream<String> values as parameters to a function created in a bloc file FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a login bloc file where I have created 2 streams username and password

```
class LoginBloc {
  LoginRepository _loginRepository = new LoginRepository();
  StreamController _loginController = StreamController<Response<LoginModel>>();

  //declare streams
  final _userName = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _password = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  //get data from streams
  StreamSink<Response<LoginModel>> get loginControllerSink =>
  _loginController.sink;
  Stream<String> get loginUserName => _userName.stream;
  Stream<String> get loginPassword => _password.stream;
  Stream<bool> get submitLoginForm =>
      Rx.combineLatest2(loginUserName, loginPassword, (a, b) => true);

  Function(String) get changeLoginUserName => _userName.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changeLoginPassword => _password.sink.add;

  //dispose
  dispose() {
    _userName.close();
    _password.close();
  }

  //functions
  login(email, password, context) async {
    try {
      LoginModel data = await _loginRepository.loginIntoSystem(email, password);
      loginControllerSink.add(Response.completed(data));    
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashboard');
    } catch (e) {
      loginControllerSink.add(Response.error(e.toString()));
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the login.dart

```
    class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  bool _passwordVisible = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final LoginBloc bloc = LoginProvider.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child:
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: size.height*0.05),
                Icon(
                  Icons.track_changes,
                  size: size.width*0.06,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: size.height*0.02),
                Text('Login',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff005D6C),
                        fontSize: size.width*0.02,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                SizedBox(height: size.height*0.04),
                Container(
                  width: size.width * 0.2,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                  child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                      stream: bloc.loginUserName,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return TextField(
                          onChanged: bloc.changeLoginUserName,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15.0),
                              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      width: 2.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'User Name',
                              hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              suffixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                size: 30.0,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                              errorText: snapshot.error),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: size.width * 0.2,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                  child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                      stream: bloc.loginPassword,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return TextField(
                          onChanged: bloc.changeLoginPassword,
                          obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                          maxLength: 20,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15.0),
                              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      width: 2.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Password',
                              hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                size: 30.0,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                  _passwordVisible
                                      ? Icons.visibility
                                      : Icons.visibility_off,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              errorText: snapshot.error),
                        );
                      }),
                ),

                Container(
                  width: size.width * 0.2,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
                    child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
                      stream: bloc.submitLoginForm,
                      builder: (context, snapshot){
                        return FlatButton(
                          color: Color(0XFFEFEFEF),
                          textColor: primaryColor,
                          disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                          disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                          onPressed: () => snapshot.hasError ? null : bloc.login(bloc.loginUserName, bloc.loginPassword, context) ,
                          child: Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am calling the login function on CLick of login button and passing the username, password and context as parameters. But on click its giving **"Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'BehaviorSubject'"**

added the loginIntoSystem:

```
Future<LoginModel> loginIntoSystem(String email, String password) 
async {
    dynamic body = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    };
    final response = await _provider.post("/login", body);
    return LoginModel.fromJson(response);
  }
```

Is there a way to convert BehaviorSubject to String ?

Comment: what params does `loginIntoSystem` take? they are not two `Stream<String>`, are they?

Comment: Also, flutter has a library called `Bloc` that works great. You might want to check it out. It will save you a lot of time and organize your code nicely. https://bloclibrary.dev/

Comment: @pskink  I have added the loginIntoSystem function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

By using value property, I was able to get the values.

```
    final fEmail = _email.value;
    final fPassword =  _password.value;
```

Thank you everyone for taking your time and posting the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. I was wrong, and behavior subject has a property `value` which returns value of that behavior subject. You can use this to get the email and password out of your behavior subject. Also, since your bloc file already has access to those variables, you don't have to pass them as arguments from your onPressed function.

```
login(context) async {
    final email = _userName.value;
    final password = _password.value;
    try {
      LoginModel data = await _loginRepository.loginIntoSystem(email, password);
      loginControllerSink.add(Response.completed(data));    
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashboard');
    } catch (e) {
      loginControllerSink.add(Response.error(e.toString()));
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: After adding 
final email = await _userName.last;
final password = await _password.last;

other lines of code are not executing. If I try to print something before 
final email = await _userName.last;
Its printing
I tried with both first and last properties

Comment: @shaluj I'm glad you figured it out. Sorry for being wrong. My memories were vague.